# How to cancel a scheduled email in mandrill?

Tags: php, json, email, laravel-4, mandrill

I am using https://github.com/abishekrsrikaanth/mailto package to handle my emails in mandrill. The package has a method to schedule an email like this.

```
$timestamp = new DateTime('+1 hour');
$mandrill = MailTo::Mandrill();
$mandrill->addRecipient($email, $name)
         ->setFrom($email, $name)
         ->setHtml($html)
         ->setText($text)
         ->setSubject($subject)
         ->send($timestamp);
```

But I can't find a way to cancel a scheduled email. I read this docs https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=cancel-scheduled

**Request JSON**

```
 {
    "key": "example key",
    "id": null
}
```

but I don't know how to implement this. Does anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the official Mandrill PHP SDK as the method to cancel a scheduled email is not implemented in the MailTo package.

```
<?php
try {
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
    $id = 'YOUR-MESSAGE-ID'; // id of scheduled message to be cancelled
    $result = $mandrill->messages->cancelScheduled($id);
    print_r($result);
} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
    echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
    throw $e;
}
?>
```

Here is the information on that https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html#method-cancel-scheduled

You simply need to pass the message id and it will be removed from the scheduled message queue. You will most probably have the message id in the response of the schedule call.

Here are the details on setting the SDK up https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html

Comment: yes the cancellation of the scheduled email is not implemented on the package. but the mandrill api docs has information about how to cancel the scheduled email through JSON request. My problem is I don't know how to implement this request.

Comment: can you give a sample snippet to your answer?